# PHP/SQL - Storing user data and accessing it

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am currently working on optimizing my PHP script. I have a table called `users` in which I store my users information, such as username, email, password etc.

I then have this (called on every page load):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && is_array($_SESSION['user']))
        $userdata=$user->getUser($_SESSION['user']['id']);
```

(The sessions is created upon logging in.)

The `getUser()` function simply looks like this:

```
    function getUser ($id)
    {
        global $dbh;

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=:id");
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $stmt->execute();

        $udata = $stmt->fetch();

        if(count($udata) == 0)
            return false;

        return $udata;
    }
```

Although I begin to see an increase in the server load, as more users registers and start using my website. According to New Relic, this specific function is causing a lot of load (since it is being accessed/loaded) so many times.

How can I store my (or access) my users data in a more optimized way?

Comment: How this reads to me is `IF the user data is already in the session THEN retrieve the user information from the DB`.  That seems redundant.

Comment: When users logins it creates the $_SESSION["user"]. If that is present, it means that the user is logged in, and then I get his information using the getUser() function.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: When they login add their info to the session and it's there until they logout.

Comment: @AbraCadaver but what if their info changes while they are logged in? And I have a lot of columns too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok to access some server side (DB, Session, Cache, etc.) storage to load user details from. So I suppose all you can do in this situation is optimizing storage access because I do not see how you can significantly improve code logic.

For example, if query execution takes a lot of time you may cache its results in memcached or redis.